# How to send HTML based data to backend using jquery ? Any Encoding or Encryption in JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am using jQuery to post data from TinyMCE Rich text editor to asp.net backend, but the problem is, i call jquery function, it gives me errors, as the Editor code is in html having double quote, single quote and other html elements which collide with javascript string which is being posted to backend asp.net using `.ajax` function, so is there anyway encode a javascript string?
Like base64_encode, serialization,

if a code is like `<label name="test">Hello</label>`, its quotes mixed with js string, and jquery denies to send it, but if we convert it into some encoded string like `yHuIolJak90@`, it can be sent to backend easily.

Please help.

Thanks
Atif

Comment: Like you say why not actually use base64? First result for 'base 64 javascript': http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html.

Comment: i did not know that base64 exists for jquery, post your solution as an answer, i may rate you.

Comment: Show us some code. I can't picture a situation where jQuery would refuse to send the data. (I'm guessing that you are bypassing jQuery's automatic escaping routines, constructing your encoded form data string by hand, submitting it, and then it failing to decode properly at the other end because you did it manually and improperly).

Comment: There's no need to use base 64. Show us how you're currently sending it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is, as you say, encoding into base 64 so that you don't have any encoding issues.

On the client side (JavaScript), you can use a small library:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

On the server side (PHP), there is a built-in function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

In fact you don't even need jQuery for the base 64 JavaScript library.

Comment: yah but web toolkit in not support by all browser

Comment: @Bhargav Mistri: I can confirm it works on IE789/Opera/Firefox/Chrome/Safari.

Comment: then ok ,because i face this problem that web toolkit work only with IE not with fire fox like rounded border

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to sanitise your input.
If the only issue is double quotes you could try URL encoding the string like this:

```
var str = your_tinyMCE_input;
alert(str);
str = encodeURI(str);
alert(str);
```

As far as encryption goes, I'm no expert so shouldn't comment. Base64 looks alright I suppose.
Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

[It just works?](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/Qa99u/)

```
<div id="sendContents">
    <h1>Works fine for me</h1>
    <label name="test">Hello</label>
</div>
```

```
$.post('backend.php', {
    myHtmlData: $('#sendContents').html()
}, function(response) {
    $('#response').html(response);
});
```

**Backend.php:**

```
<?php echo '<b>'.$_POST['myHtmlData'].'</b>' ?>
```

Can we see your code that doesn't work?